# Network-wide badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, stack-exchange

It seems to me that's very tricky to get people engaged in a SE site outside of the one they initially joined. One incentive might be to introduce network-wide badges.

These might include, for example:

- Having over 1000 reputation on 5+ SE sites
- Have a question with 5+ upvotes on 5+ SE sites
- Have an answer with 10+ upvotes on 5+ SE sites
- etc.

I'd personally like to see this, but I think it might be good for SE as a whole, too.

Comment: IMO that network-wide reputation badge should not include the association bonus.

Comment: "*It seems to me that's very tricky to get people engaged in a SE site outside of the one they initially joined.*" -- can you support your claim using empirical data or at least with related meta posts? Also, doesn't flair already show off your participation on the whole network? I do not oppose your idea but I'm having hard time understanding the merit of your proposal.

Comment: @Firelord I carefully said, "it seems to me", but the reason I came to this conclusion is by looking at the average person's profile when I engage with them: They nearly always only have one meaningful presence on an SE site (your network profile is a typical example, for instance, of someone who is primarily engaged in one SE site, with only a small amount of time on others). Meanwhile I see newer SE sites struggling to get the sort of traction that the original three did. I could be wrong, but as I said, it seems to me otherwise.